# Zimbra - Docker-Compose loop

Tags: docker, docker-compose, zimbra

I have a Zimbra email server I'm running in docker. I created it with docker-compose with some local volumes so I can back the whole thing up. I got it all up and working, and to test I rebuilt the container, but during the install process it gets stuck. Here is a copy of the docker-compose.yaml file.

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  zimbra:
    image: jorgedlcruz/zimbra
    container_name: zimbra
    hostname: fake.domain.com
    environment:
      - TZ=${TZ}
    ports:
      - 25:25
      - 80:80
      - 465:465
      - 587:587
      - 110:110
      - 143:143
      - 993:993
      - 995:995
      - 443:443
      - 8080:8080
      - 8443:8443
      - 7071:7071
      - 9071:9071
      - 389:389
      - 636:636
      - 5222:5222
      - 5223:5223
      - 5269:5269
    dns:
      - 127.0.0.1
      - 8.8.8.8
    environment:
      PASSWORD: ********
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.226.13
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - '/etc/docker/zimbra/data:/opt/zimbra'

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: pub_net
volumes:
  zimbra_data:
    driver: local
```

The rebuild starts, and the container detects that an install already exists. At which point the log displays this over and over:

> The system will be modified.  Continue? [N]  Exit? [N]  The system
> will be modified.  Continue? [N]  Exit? [N]  The system will be
> modified.  Continue? [N]  Exit? [N]  The system will be modified.
> Continue? [N]  Exit? [N]  The system will be modified.  Continue? [N]
> Exit? [N]  The system will be modified.  Continue? [N]  Exit? [N]  The
> system will be modified.  Continue? [N]  Exit? [N]  The system will be
> modified.  Continue? [N]  Exit? [N]

I have to force the container down to stop it. Does anyone know how I can let the container know that I am okay with changes being made so that the process can continue?